# CouchDB/Iris Couch - noob security question

Tags: couchdb

I've been playing with Iris Couch using Futon, curl and reading the [CouchDB security Wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authentication_database) and I'm a little confused about readers, admins & server admins.

Am I correct in saying that the "Create Server Admin" pop-up in Futon isn't *actually* creating a server admin, (the wiki mentions this is only done by editing a local.ini file)?

What you're really doing is creating documents in the _users database - giving users a username & password to authenticate with,  after which their name or role is compared to any names/roles defined against a database security object?

Also, I noticed that the "require_valid_user" is set to false by default, so assuming Iris Couch has a server admin, does this mean that although users have to provide their username/password to authenticate - they're validated as anonymous, so no comparison is made against any database-defined security?

If I want to restrict a user to a specific database, do I need the "require_valid_user" setting to be set to true?

Cheers

Comment: OK - thanks to [Jason](http://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/security_problem-qy2g2?utm_content=topic_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification) I realised I was missing a crucial bit of info - creating server admins creates a reference for that user in the "admin" section of your configuration. This basically means that the user can do what they like(!) regardless of the _security database as in my case. Once I removed my test2 user reference from that section, they no longer had any access to the db - as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the "Create server admin" popup form, that is the same as editing the .ini files. (Internally, Futon will query the a /_config URL which is an HTTP API to edit the .ini files.)

The `_users` database is the authoritative location for all user acounts, their passwords, and their roles. When a user queries CouchDB with a password (or with a session cookie), that name and role will be used to grant or deny their query. The decision of whether to allow or disallow their query is made by checking the `_security` object in the database first. They must be in the "readers" section: either their name is in the "names" list, or their role must be in the "roles" list.

I recommend that you [avoid the require_valid_user option](http://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/require_valid_user_error#reply_6336022). It is for very specialized situations.

Comment: Thanks Jason - that's exactly what I though was happening.

However, I have the following _security set against a test db - `{"admins":{"names":["neil"],"roles":["admin"]},"readers":{"names":["guest"],"roles":["guest"]}}`.

When I created a new server admin - `{"_id":"org.couchdb.user:test2","_rev":"1-084965a94ea3d7a24116f33245a0ef95","name":"test2","type":"user","roles":[]}` - this user can read from my test db?

Because neither this users name nor role appear in the _security document I'd expect them *not* to be able to be authorized?

Comment: user `test2` should *not* be able to read with readers = `{"names":["guest"],"roles":["guest"]}`. If you are having issues, perhaps join Freenode IRC #couchdb or email the users mailing list. It's probably something simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can have database-specific users and roles. You need to modify the `_security` "document" for a given database. It's also documented [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authorization) on the wiki.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been reading that wiki page, hence why I included it in my post.

What I'm asking for is some confirmation of the behaviour I'm seeing - I have database specific users and roles, but if I create a user in the _users database, that user can do anything, irrespective of the _security document.